# Disable remote ftp in OS X but allow ftp from localhost

Tags: macos, sftp

I am running OS X 8.5

I want to disable remote FTP but allow local FTP because I need to use SFTP.

Is there a quick command that might handle this?

Comment: Don't allow FTP through your network firewall. Done.

Comment: Hi , I am reading the documentation on ftpd.conf but can't seem to find any clue as to how to disable remote ftp. Is this possible at all without  having to resort to your suggestion?

Comment: If you don't want to allow remote FTP connections why would you allow it inbound through your firewall? Wouldn't that be the best solution, regardless of the settings in the OS?

Comment: Thank you Joe, should I just use ipfw like so deny tcp from any to server-ip dst-port 21 ?

Comment: FTP & SFTP are not related. Disabling FTP will not have any impact on SFTP. Or do you mean FTPS ?

Comment: Actually I just found out there is an SFTP server on Mac OS X , i stand corrected.